# Work done when applying an electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, dielectric

On these [example questions](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/materials-science-and-engineering/3-00-thermodynamics-of-materials-fall-2002/assignments/exweek4.PDF) from MIT in the solution to 4.1 they write the work done by applying the electric field to be: 
$$W=V_0 \int \vec E \cdot d \vec D$$
Where does this equation come from and what is $V_0$ in this case.

Comment: You should include the exercise test into the question so that one doesn't have to click a link to understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V_0$ is likely the volume of the dielectric medium.

The equation itself follows from
$$\delta W = \int\phi\delta\rho\mathrm{d}^3 x$$
where $\phi$ is the electrostatic potential and $\delta$ singifies a small change in the corresponding quantity. Now, by Maxwell's equations, $\rho = \nabla\cdot\vec D$. Some manipulations and neglecting a surface integral lead to
$$\delta W = -\int \nabla\phi\cdot\delta D\mathrm{d}^3x$$
and $-\nabla \phi = \vec E$ leads to
$$ \delta W = \int \vec E\cdot\delta \vec D\mathrm{d}^3 x$$
so the total work is
$$ W = \int_0^D\int_V \vec E\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec D\mathrm{d}^3 x$$